# Is there axual/platform-test-standalone version supporting jdk 17

Tags: java, docker, spring-kafka

Hellow I want to use for local development

axual/platform-test-standalone image

The issue is that I want to have one that is compatible with java 17 and not just with 11. I was trying with multiple versions but I could not find any version to work.

Docker image is like this

```
  app:
    image: axual/platform-test-standalone:5.7.0
    hostname: standalone
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    volumes:
      - ./artifacts:/schemaJars
    environment:
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=app
```

Of course because of mismatch from java app and the image I get this error

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0

Are you aware if there is any axual verison for 17 ?